# What causes Jetty BadMessage: 400 No Host?

Tags: jetty, maven-jetty-plugin, http-status-code-400

I'm runny Jetty 9.0.6.v20130930 via Maven with the command `mvn jetty:run`.

Looking through my server logs, every couple of days I'm getting this message:

2014-01-28 00:57:47.659:WARN:oejh.HttpParser:qtp975361377-71: BadMessage: 400 No Host for HttpChannelOverHttp@66a7150e{r=0,a=IDLE,uri=-}

I haven't been able to replicate it, and it doesn't appear to happening in the vicinity of any other requests, which I would expect if there were someone using the site.  What I'd like to know is what might be causing it, and what the user (if there is one) is seeing when it happens?

Answer (score 2):

maybe somebody post streaming request to your website. for example: a websocket handshake request.
reference link:
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=417589